# Jquery clone form fields and insert the corrisponding data from db

Tags: jquery

In my contact page I use the clone function to duplicate the rows of the form

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <span id="cloneRowTest" class="label label-primary pointer">
                Add <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ROW 5 CLONABLE-ROW-LABEL -->
    <div class="row cust-gutters clonable-row-label hidden">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <label class="control-label" for="mansione">Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <label class="control-label" for="nominativo">Phone</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <label class="control-label" for="telefono">Email</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ROW 5 CLONABLE-ROW -->
    <div class="row cust-gutters clonable-row hidden">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="contacts[name][]" placeholder="..." />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="contacts[phone][]" placeholder="..." />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="contacts[email][]" placeholder="..." />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

.

```
$('#cloneRowTest').on('click', function() {
    var num = $('.clonable-row').length;
    if($('.clonable-row:first').hasClass('hidden')) {
        $('.clonable-row:first, .clonable-row-label').fadeToggle(0).toggleClass('hidden');
    } else {
        if(num < 4) {
            $('.clonable-row:first').clone(true).hide().insertAfter('.clonable-row:last').fadeIn(0);
            $('.clonable-row:last').find('input').each(function() {
                $(this).val('');
            });
        }
    }
});
```

[Bootply](https://www.codeply.com/go/bp/IWpIfqWGoy)

Now I would like to create a "edit" page (with the same functionality) and would like to generate rows and
insert the corresponding values taken from a db but I have several problems.

My ajax object response

```
data = [
    Object { name="Foo",  phone=87654321,  email="foo@email.com"},
    Object { name="Bar",  phone=12345678,  email="bar@yahoo.com"}
]
```

Code for clone rows and insert the corrisponding data

```
$.each(data, function(idx, obj) {
    $('#cloneRowTest').trigger('click');
    //alert(); // With this alert are cloned the correct number of rows!  (timeout problem?)
    $.each(obj, function(k, v) {
        $('input[name="contacts[' + k + '][]"]').val(v);
    });
});
```

1. Only one row is created (should be 2)
2. When I can clone the correct lines, all fields of the rows are the same (the last of data object)

How could I do this?
Thank you

Comment: I know its not an answer to the actual question: but I created a jquery plugin ( https://github.com/corinis/jsForm ) that does pretty much what you need, and it takes care of the collection handling (i.e. duplicating html based on the data)

Comment: isolate the row of inputs you are updating values to in the last `each` in question. Otherwise you set all inputs with same name every iteration

Comment: @charlietfl - How can I isolate the row of input? thanks

Comment: try to target inputs in last row only.

Comment: @charlietfl - Unfortunately I can't figure out how to do. Could you show me how to do it? Thank you